# Zassenhaus Lemma

Tags: group-theory

In (almost) all books of Algebra/ Group Theory, the [Zassenhaus Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_lemma) is used only to prove [Schreier Refinement Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_refinement_theorem)  (or to prove [Jordan-Holder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93H%C3%B6lder_theorem#Uniqueness%3a_Jordan.E2.80.93H.C3.B6lder_theorem)).

What are other applications of Zassenhaus Lemma in group theory?

Comment: Good question.  It seems to be well-established that Zassenhaus developed his lemma (as an undergraduate student!) precisely to give a smoother proof of Schreier Refinement.  I know (well, "je connais") that ZL has a generalization to modular lattices, but that seems not to count as an answer to your question.

Comment: yes! If I am correct, he established this result at the age 21.

Comment: Zassenhaus butterfly lemma is applied to compute the Euler characteristic of any generalized flag variety attached to a shape module. This does not count as an application in group theory, I am afraid.